# After working great, today Font Awesome stopped loading. net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: javascript

My kit is set to use "latest" and it's the only kit I've ever installed on my website.

I copied the pertinent code into my site header, as shown below. All worked great, until today.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Place your kit's code here -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/47cf353fe3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Ready to use Font Awesome. Activate interlock. Dynotherms - connected. Infracells - up. Icons are go! -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Out of the blue, the FA server stopped serving the content, and my Chrome (on Mac) started giving me "net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" on the following. The "status" just shows as "failed":

In: 47cf353fe3.js:2

GET https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/js/free-v4-shims.min.js net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

GET https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/js/free.min.js 
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

GET https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/js/conflict-detection.min.js net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: For reference, the developers are aware of the issue and are working to fix it. Here's a link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/16482. You can also check this website for the status: https://status.fortawesome.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the status of a third party service and thus can only really be remedied by those in charge of maintaining that service.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, it started working again. Seems to have been a server issue. Sorry for posting such in the wrong place. I was sent here by their support page.

Comment: I'm with you, @MihaiChelaru. Seems eminently closeable.

Comment: @DougJoseph Glad to hear it's working again. The issue seemed to be upstream of FontAwesome itself, as their CDN provider, StackPath, was having issues: https://status.stackpath.com/incidents/22c999cbl1nh

Comment: @MihaiChelaru: Got it. Thanks.